# Postgres: LIKE query against a string returns no results, though results exist

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-like

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here.  I'm trying to get a list of results from Postgres, and I know the rows exist since I can see them when I do a simple `SELECT *`.  However, when I try to do a `LIKE` query, I get nothing back.

Sample data:

```
{
  id: 1,
  userId: 2,
  cache: '{"dataset":"{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Test\",\"directory\":\"/data/"...'
};
```

Example:

```
SELECT cache FROM storage_table WHERE cache LIKE '%"dataset":"{\"id\":4%';
```

Is there some escaping I need?

Comment: The data in question is JSON, but our database isn't up the version of Postgres that has the JSON field types/operations built in.

Answer (score 3):

The LIKE operator supports escaping of wildcards (e.g. so that you can search for an underscore or `%` sign). The default escape character is a backslash.

In order to tell the `LIKE` operator that you do **not** want to use the backslash as an ESCAPE character you need to define a different one, e.g. the `~`

```
SELECT cache 
FROM storage_table 
WHERE cache LIKE '%"dataset":"{\"id\":4%' ESCAPE '~';
```

You can use *any* character that does not appear in your data, `ESCAPE '#'` or `ESCAPE '§'`

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7703f/1

---

But you should seriously consider upgrading to a more recent Postgres version that fully supports JSON. Not only will your queries be more robust, they can also be a **lot** faster due to the ability to index a JSON document.